# How do I return the contents of this function to the client side?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, netlify

I have a function that I call using

```
     fetch(http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/token-hider? 
     stateName=' +stateName)
```

on my client side.

the token-hider function looks like this:

```
const qs = require("qs");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

var alertEndpoint = "";
var parkEndpoint = "";
var parksWithAlerts = "";



exports.handler = async function getURLS(event, context, callback) 
{
  // Get env var values defined in our Netlify site UI
 const {api_key, alert_api_url, park_api_url} = process.env;

  var stateName =event.queryStringParameters.stateName;
  alertEndpoint = `${alert_api_url}${stateName}${api_key}`;
  parkEndpoint = `${park_api_url}${stateName}${api_key}`;

 getData();



 async function getData(alertsArea, alertHeader) {


 const [getAlertData, getParkData] = await 
 Promise.all([fetch(alertEndpoint), fetch(parkEndpoint)] );


 var alertResults = await getAlertData.json();
 var parkResults=  await getParkData.json();
 var alertData = alertResults.data;
 var parkData = parkResults.data;

 parksWithAlerts = parkData.map(park => {
  park.alertData = alertData.filter(alert => alert.parkCode === 
  park.parkCode);
  return park

  });

  console.log(parksWithAlerts);

   }
 console.log(callback);
 };
```

how could I return the contents of parksWithAlerts back to the client side after this function is finished?

Answer (score 1):

Try to learn more about **callback** functions in Javascript.
It is right there in your code, the `callback` that you are printing is actually suppose to be called after you have executed your code and you can do like this `callback(parksWithAlerts);`.
While calling the function `getURLS` you will provide the function which is suppose to get called with args.

Examples : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-callbacks/

Comment: if I am using the fetch method, could I just return parksWithAlerts as a promise instead? or would a callback be better?

Comment: @ScottCaudle,  As fetch method is a http call, you better return a promise instead of callback.

Comment: got it, so the only thing I can't figure out is how to return parksWithAlerts as a promise of the client side fetch which was fetch(http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/token-hider? 
     stateName=' +stateName)

Comment: more on it, you can find it here.. https://flaviocopes.com/fetch-api/
Hope this helps.

Comment: when returning a promise in lambda functions, you don't need the callback. The handler knows it is a promise. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with error handling and returning a response type of JSON

**`token-hider`**

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

// Get env var values defined in our Netlify site UI
const {api_key, alert_api_url, park_api_url} = process.env;

async function getJson(response) {
  return await response.json();
}

const alertEndpoint = stateName => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fetch(`${alert_api_url}${stateName}${api_key}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) { // NOT res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300
          return reject({ statusCode: response.status, body: response.statusText });
        }
        return resolve(getJson(response))
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('alertEndpoint invocation error:', err); // output to netlify function log
        reject({ statusCode: 500, body: err.message });
      })
  });
}

const parkEndpoint = stateName => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  fetch(`${park_api_url}${stateName}${api_key}`)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) { // NOT res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300
        return reject({ statusCode: response.status, body: response.statusText });
      }
      return resolve(getJson(response))
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('parkEndpoint invocation error:', err); // output to netlify function log
      reject({ statusCode: 500, body: err.message });
    })
  })
}

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  const stateName = event.queryStringParameters.stateName;
  return Promise.all([alertEndpoint(stateName), parkEndpoint(stateName)])
    .then(values => {
      const [alertData, parkData] = values;
      const parksWithAlerts = parkData.map(park => {
        park.alertData = alertData.filter(alert => alert.parkCode === park.parkCode);
        return park;
        });
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(parksWithAlerts)
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
};
```

***NOTE:*** If you are trying to hide the token, make sure to not deploy this from a public repository on Netlify.

Also, this code has not been tested 100%, so there may be some things to resolve. The response layout and structure is something I use in a few of my lambda functions on Netlify.